# Command to search for a string in all of the previous commits of a user

Tags: git

I changed something about 1 week ago and I realized that it impacted something today. But the question is I have no idea what I changed, but I do have a hint of what I changed.

What is the command to view all my own previous commits and search in the files I changed for a specific text string?

Comment: [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) is your friend.  Specifically take a look at the `--author`, `-S` and `--since` options.

Comment: apparently you read that 100 page git log documentation page. care to explain those options? because i can't find a -S option. An example would be nice. I'm not a genius like you. The answer "RTFM" is not an answer, even tho you gave a hint. I'm sure when you were starting out, you found it annoying to get someone to say just read the docs. thanks anyway.